# Hand over mousedown event to iframe covered by another element

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have an iframe covered with semitransparent div. The iframe document wants to capture mousedown event, but the div above prevents it. Is there a way to hand over the event to the iframe?

Minimal code to reproduce and testing:

**main document**

```
<div style="width: 320px; height: 200px; position: relative">
    <div style="background: #0007; position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0"></div>
    <iframe src="testFrame.html" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

**testFrame.html**

```
<style>
    body { margin: 0; }
    #elem { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
</style>

<div id="elem">
    Frame
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("elem").addEventListener("mousedown", _=>alert("click"));
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like [pointer-events: none](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the overlay?

Comment: @Yogi bulls eye. Setting pointer events to none to the overlay and auto to the iframe did the trick. I would accept this as an answer if you want to post it as such.

Answer (score 0):

As @Yogi suggested in the comment, it can be resolved by setting [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

`none`

> The element is never the target of pointer events; however, pointer events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value.

So one way is to set the `none` value to the container and `auto` to the iframe` (so the overlay div is kind of redundant):

```
<div style="pointer-events: none; ...">
    <div style="background: #0007; ..."></div>
    <iframe src="testFrame.html" style="pointer-events: auto"></iframe>
</div>
```

The other way is to set the `none` value to the overlay:

```
<div style="...">
    <div style="background: #0007; pointer-events: none; ..."></div>
    <iframe src="testFrame.html" style="..."></iframe>
</div>
```